# Xcode 5.1 only 64-bit simulator in instruments

Tags: ios, xcode5.1

I just updated my xcode to 5.1...  Installed all the simulators i needed (6, 7, 7.1 ) and can happily debug in each one.

However, the profiler now always starts the 64-bit retina 7.1 iphone simulator. Tried with time profiler, allocations, zombies, same exact simulator. Tried to switch it in the simulator's own menu, tried to restart instruments, xcode, nothing works.
The "Profile" scheme has ticked the "Use the Run action's arguments", but doesn't happen anything. Also, didn't change manually anything in the project's settings before or after the update.

Is there a workaround or fix for this issue ?

Any response much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same problem as I wanted to profile against the iPhone Retina 3.5-inch simulator. As a workaround I used Instruments from the command line:

```
instruments -t $InstrumentsTemplate  -w "iPhone Retina (3.5-inch) - Simulator - iOS 7.1" $AppLocation
```

where `$InstrumentsTemplate` is the path to the profiling template you want to use with Instruments and in my case was:

`Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Resources/templates/Time Profiler.tracetemplate`

and `$AppLocation` is the path to the app you want to profile and looks like this:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/658FE3GB-49B6-48F5-B6A6-0D1C8D1F6BFD/AppName.app
```

To see a list of all Instruments templates that you can pass with `-t` use:

```
instruments -s
```

To see a list of all available simulators that you can pass with `-w` use:

```
instruments -s devices
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I'll try it a bit later. Thought there is a way without struggling in command line with paths and parameters. So sad :(

Comment: This actually works, but it's really annoying entering all those parameters then manually open the generated output for analysis. Accepting your answer, hope Apple will resolve this issue soon.

Comment: Did you file a bug? Otherwise, assume they will not resolve it. (We only just ran into this, so I have yet to file one.)

Comment: I just ran into this and filed as radr://16533313.

Comment: @DavidDunham I didn't as I wasn't sure if it's something wrong only on my side or others have the same problem too :)

Comment: Filing duplicate bugs is one way Apple can realize that it is affecting many developers. (I did get around to filing this one, rdar://16514644.) And who knows, yours may be the first, or have the best repro steps.

Comment: "Error starting recording", every time. OH how I hate meaningless error messages!

Answer (score 15):

There is a way to avoid using the command line here. Do your "Profile" step from Xcode as you normally would, but choose the "Target" pulldown, head to "Options", and choose a different "Simulator Configuration" to match the version you'd like.

[image]

Then, just use the Library to drag over whatever things you'd like to measure that match any of the predefined sets (and even add more). Then hit Record and off you go. In past experience, sometimes I had to quit the simulator if it was already open, but not sure if that's necessary now.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it's working and it's much faster than from command line.

Comment: You'll have to stop the profiler to open the pulldown.